# Angular2: How to import a stylesheet from node_modules?

Tags: css, angular

**Question:** In my Angular2 (4.0) app, how can I import stylesheets (css) from a module in node_modules?

I have a module located here:

```
node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable
```

I want to import this stylesheet:

```
node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css
```

*I've tried the following approaches*, with no luck:

In my components own scss file:

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css';
```

In my component:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'site_table',
  template: require('./site_table.html'),
  styleUrls: ['./site_table.scss', '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css']
})
```

Comment: Have you tried this `@import 'node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you're already using SCSS, in your `./site_table.scss` import it like so

```
@import "~swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index";
```

Note: do not add the extension.

It will import stylesheet from node package. That served my well, hope it will do for you too. That way you just have to use single stylesheet in your component and it will look cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using new the angular-cli with the angular.json file and not webpack, the tilde (~) in @sickelap's answer probably doesn't work for you.

Instead what you can do is add this in your angular.json file:-

```
        ...
        "styles": [
          ...
        ],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "node_modules/@swimlane"
          ]
        },
        ...
```

Then, in your component's .scss file, insert this:

`@import "ngx-datatable/release/index";`

Note that the `.css` extension is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a complete relative url:

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'site_table',
  template: require('./site_table.html'),
  styleUrls: [
          './site_table.scss', 
          '../../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.css' 
  ]
})
```

Didn't tried your notation but node package resolution might not work without webpack. I may be wrong though.