# Correct path to dist-folder

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was trying to use, with angular:

https://material.io/develop/web/components/drawers/

I realized I can not use

```css
@import "@material/drawer/mdc-drawer";
@import "@material/list/mdc-list";
```

Because I use CSS.

To make it work, I decided to put

```
styleUrls: [
    '...',
    "~@material/drawer/dist/mdc.drawer.min.css"
]
```

This does not work, he can not find it.

What is the right way ?

Both do not work, this is like the image for the Path:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YJCx.jpg

Comment: you need the full path, try node_modules/@material/drawer/dist/mdc.drawer.min.css or see @swapnil N answer

Comment: updated my post, both suggestions seem not to work

Answer (score 0):

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
      "./node_modules"
]}
```

Just include node_modules path into angular.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add below

```
styleUrls: [
    '...',
    "../../node_modules/@material/drawer/dist/mdc.drawer.min.css"
]
```

please refer this post if it is helpful. [Angular2: How to import a stylesheet from node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738008/angular2-how-to-import-a-stylesheet-from-node-modules?rq=1)